# Process multiple ajax requests synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an object with labels and urls, which I would like to expand into object with same keys but replace urls with the actual content obtained via ajax call, for example:

```
var requests = {
  foo: 'http://url1.com',
  bar: null,
  baz: 'http://url2.com'
}
```

would expand to an object like

```
{
  foo: 'content 1',
  baz: 'content 2'
}
```

Individual items can be expanded in any order, but obviously I want to skip the ajax calls for `null` values. The main point is that I also want to have a callback that will be called after the object is fully expanded.

I was wondering what is the most elegant and simple solution for this (in jQuery)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably use jQuery's `when()` and `then()` functions for ajax calls.

Note that this is still *async*. Sync requests would lock your browser until finished. Hence, the most elegant solution is to do it async, and use deferreds/promises.

```js
var promises = [];
var results = {}
var requests = {
  foo: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  bar: null,
  baz: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2'
}

function getDataForKey(key, url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      document.write(key + " done<br>");
      results[key] = data;
    }
  });
}

for (var key in requests) {
  if (!requests[key]) continue;
  promises.push(getDataForKey(key, requests[key]));
}

// Apply each promise as an argument to jQuery's when() function
$.when.apply(this, promises).then(function() {
  // Here everything has finished.
  document.write("all done!<br>");
  document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(results, null, "  ") + "</pre>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```